# Polygon to vertices and edge indices

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, shapely, vertices

Lets say we have a polygon and need the vertices and edges.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

lat_point_list = [50.854457, 52.518172, 50.072651, 48.853033, 50.854457]
lon_point_list = [4.377184, 13.407759, 14.435935, 2.349553, 4.377184]

polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lon_point_list, lat_point_list))
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[polygon_geom])
coords_rounded = []
all_coords = []

for i, row in polygon.iterrows():
    ring = list(row.geometry.exterior.coords)
    ring.pop()
    if row.geometry.exterior.is_ccw == False:
        #-- to get proper orientation of the normals
        ring.reverse()
        
    for j, v in enumerate(ring[:-1]):
        rounded_x = round(float(ring[j][0]), 2)
        rounded_y = round(float(ring[j][1]), 2)
        rounded_z = 100
        coords_rounded.append((rounded_x, rounded_y, rounded_z))
        all_coords.append([rounded_x, rounded_y, rounded_z]) 

    #-- last-first edge
    rounded_x = round(float(ring[-1][0]), 2)
    rounded_y = round(float(ring[-1][1]), 2)
    rounded_z = 100
    coords_rounded.append((rounded_x, rounded_y, rounded_z))
    all_coords.append([rounded_x, rounded_y, rounded_z]) 

print(all_coords)
```

`[[2.35, 48.85, 100], [14.44, 50.07, 100], [13.41, 52.52, 100], [4.38, 50.85, 100]]`

Gives me the vertices in the format I need.  A `list` with faces in the proper orientation where the order of the nodes define the normal vector pointing outward. I now need the indices of the coordinates in the form:

```
[[1351, 1358],
 [1358, 1360],
 [1360, 1359]...]
```

How do I extract the indices that define the edges of the polygon. A `list-of-lists` where where each element is the index of the to- and from-coordinate (of an edge) from the `print(all_coords)` `list`? I need a closed polygon please.

Comment: It's not 100% clear from your example where the numbers `1351, 1358...` come from and why they do not simply increase with a +1 step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can simplify your code because your first `ring` is:

```py
[(4.377184, 50.854457),
 (13.407759, 52.518172),
 (14.435935, 50.072651),
 (2.349553, 48.853033),
 (4.377184, 50.854457)]
```

and you pop its last element:

```py
ring.pop() # pops out: (4.377184, 50.854457)
```

so `ring` becomes:

```py
[(4.377184, 50.854457),
 (13.407759, 52.518172),
 (14.435935, 50.072651),
 (2.349553, 48.853033)]
```

and then you loop over `ring[:,-1]` which is only `[(4.377184, 50.854457), (13.407759, 52.518172), (14.435935, 50.072651)]` so you are missing your last vertex `(2.349553, 48.853033)`. That's why you must add it back at the end.

You can avoid that by simplifying your code:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

lat_point_list = [50.854457, 52.518172, 50.072651, 48.853033, 50.854457]
lon_point_list = [4.377184, 13.407759, 14.435935, 2.349553, 4.377184]

polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lon_point_list, lat_point_list))
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[polygon_geom])
all_coords = []
edges = []

for i, row in polygon.iterrows():
    exterior = row.geometry.exterior
    ring = list(exterior.coords)
    ring.pop() # pop out duplicate vertice
    if exterior.is_ccw == False:
        #-- to get proper orientation of the normals
        ring.reverse()

    for j, v in enumerate(ring):
        edges.append([j,j+1])
        rounded_x = round(float(v[0]), 2)
        rounded_y = round(float(v[1]), 2)
        rounded_z = 100
        all_coords.append([rounded_x, rounded_y, rounded_z]) 
    
    edges.append([j+1,0])

print(all_coords)
print(edges)
```

which prints the same result:
`[[2.35, 48.85, 100], [14.44, 50.07, 100], [13.41, 52.52, 100], [4.38, 50.85, 100]]`

in addition with the indices of the vertices:
`[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 0]]`

But it's not 100% clear from your code why your indices do not simply increase with a +1 increment... A point in a ring should directly follow its previous neighbor.

Comment: I am grateful to you. I am experiencing challenges. I've asked another question -> https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448431/missing-indices-when-extracting-vertices-and-edges-from-polygon